# Rebuild search index prestashop 1.7

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I moved database data (products,categories etc) from prestashop 1.6 to 1.7.x. Now I want rebuild search index, but can't find it in to admin panel. 
How to rebuild search index in prestashop 1.7?

Answer (score 6):

Prestashop 1.7 search indexing settings are in `Shop Parameters > Search` tab.

[image]